# Retrieving Email contacts from Hotmail

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hotmail

I am new to stackeoverflow. I am trying to retrieve email address of contacts from Hotmail in asp.net.But its giving email hashes.

How can i get the email address of the contacts?below is the response i get from the API.

```
{
   "id": "contact.ca49847541d000000000000000000000000", 
   "first_name": abc, 
   "last_name": xyz, 
   "name": "test@test.net", 
   "gender": null, 
   "is_friend": true, 
   "is_favorite": false, 
   "user_id": "XXXXXXX4d520c", 
   "email_hashes": [
      "abbfa2d656170aa1b4bd596047b98f0a2cc7b106ccfd83434e6caff01c2bdd77"
   ], 
   "updated_time": "2011-11-12T08:15:26+0000"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows live api get email contact vs email hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210265/windows-live-api-get-email-contact-vs-email-hash)

Comment: @Quentin but the link you provided has no answers and I guess it can be reposted

Comment: @nuux — No, [you should edit it or post a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21012/19068)

Answer (score 1):

Some more information:

> A hash is not designed to be "decoded", The point is for you to be
>   able to check it against an email address or addresses you already
>   have.

Source and possible duplicate: [How to convert hash into text from the response of Live API for Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370141/how-to-convert-hash-into-text-from-the-response-of-live-api-for-contacts)

Because someone decided to downvote me, I did some more research. There's no way you'll get the email addresses from these hashes. You need to find another way to retrieve your contacts and there emailadresses. So far, I did not find any sollution to do this.

I've found some non-free services that will give you what you need. Other than those, it seems only big companies are able to get the emailaddresses of all the contacts. I guess Microsoft benefits from security and sells this option for big money.

Here's one service you can use:

> http://stescodes.com/grabcontacts.aspx

**UPDATE:**
[OpenContacts.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/) is open-source library for importing contacts from popular web-mail services. Now supports: GMail, Yahoo! Mail, Live (Hotmail).

Have a nice day.

Comment: I have found solution for this at http://cloudsponge.codeplex.com/
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Arent't you gonna need a subscription at cloudsponge for this for 25$/month or 275$/year? I've added another sollution (non free) to my answer.

Comment: I think i finally found a free sollution. Check out the update in my answer.